# NSDate not converting properly to format only for 12:00 PM

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

This is how I'm converting my date to appear on a uilabel:

In my view:

```
self.label.text = [Utils stringFromDate:date format:@"a hh:mm"];
```

In Utils:

```
+ (NSCalendar *)xCalendar {
return [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
}

+ (NSDateFormatter *)xDateFormatter {
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
df.calendar = [Utils xCalendar];
return df;
}

+ (NSString *)stringFromDate:(NSDate *)date format:(NSString *)formatStr {
NSDateFormatter *df = [Utils xDateFormatter];
[df setDateFormat:formatStr];
return [df stringFromDate:date];
}
```

Now if the data is 11:00 AM, it is working properly. However, if the data is anything from 12:00 PM to 12:59 PM, the label will display 12:00 AM to 12:59 AM. 1:00 PM will work properly. Why is this happening?

Comment: My question is why `a hh:mm` and not `hh:mm a`?

Answer (score 0):

Pass "HH:mm a" dateformat in your function parameter

```
[Utils stringFromDate:date format:@"HH:mm a"];
```

For set more Timezone format, to "[Click here](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns)"